# Adding variables to HTML email in PHP

Tags: php, email

I am using this script to send an HTML email

```
  $to = 'receiver@domain.tld';

  $subject = 'Test Email';

  $headers = "From: email@domain.tld\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: email@domain.tld\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

  $message = $htmlContent = file_get_contents("email_template.html");

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But I would like to add some variables like custom greeting with name etc. into the email. But I am not sure how to do that since I am using

```
$message = $htmlContent = file_get_contents("email_template.html");
```

To get the email content is because when I pasted the html content directly into the php code, the email got sent but the styling was broken for some reason...this way it works perfectly, but I don't know how to add variables.

Any help, please?

Comment: so, what you need is to pass variable to the template? (html file)

Comment: PHP code in a file doesn't get executed by `file_get_contents`.

Comment: maybe you can try preg_replace or str_replace() and do like <h1>hello [name]</h1>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One rudimentary solution would be to change your template to be a `.php` file, and have it echo some simple variables.

**email_template.php**

```
Hello <?php echo $firstName ?>,

This message is to notify you...
```

Now you can setup these variables in your script before you load the template.

Load it using `include` so that the PHP is evaluated, and capture the result using output buffering:

```
$firstName = "John";

ob_start();
include("email_template.php");
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Now your `$message` will contain the HTML email content with the dynamic first name variable.

*This is a very basic solution.*

Another option would be to use placeholders in your HTML template (like `%first_name%`) and to do string replacement.

Ultimately you may want instead to start looking at real templating options like [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). I also recommend you look at PHP mail libraries like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of using the raw `mail` function.

Comment: I've tried the include method, but this has resulted in the email_template.php being displayed when opening the php with this script and the email that it sent contained just the letter '1' and nothing else

Comment: @user1207524 - you'd need to change your *email_template.php* so that it returns a string containing the HTML: see [example 5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). This would allow you to assign the contents of the included file to a variable - otherwise `include` merely returns a boolean which is why you're getting `1` in the email (i.e. `true`).

Comment: @user1207524 refresh my answer, I've updated to show how you can capture the template output with buffering.